# Extend a class that contains a field of the same type of the extending class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a question about extending classes in Java.
I 4 classes:

```
Class A {
private static B variableB;
private static C variableC;
private static D variableD;

//some methods
}

Class B extends A{
//...//
}

Class C extends A{
//...//
}

Class D extends A{
//...//
}
```

Is it ok to extend a class that contains a field of the same type of the extending classes?
Is there any better solution?

In B, C, D I have to use methods that are declared in A and in A I have to call methods that are declared in B, C, or D.

Comment: If you want to use the super class method you can call super method to implement.

Comment: Cyclic dependencies (implicit or explicit) are considered as code smells. If A needs methods from B,C, D and B, C, D need methods from A, add methods from B, C, D to A. Without more details on a real example rather than A, B, C, D.. It's tough to comment on the right way to go forward..

Comment: Class having a "field of the same type" is very common.  Linked list is one example. Decorator pattern is another. As for cross dependencies: try to avoid it.

Comment: You don't extend a class just because you need to call methods of that class. You exend a class because there exists an *is a* association between the two. Your description is too vague and abstract to recommend anything, but you're probably abusing inheritance, and also probably abusing static members.